# VS Code Failing to Launch Flutter App on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble launching my flutter app on my MacBook Pro. What's worse is that I can't find VS Code logs to troubleshoot the problem. Using VS Code, my app has launched successfully from a desktop running Fedora 38 in Chrome and on an Android emulator. The same successful launches happened from a laptop running Windows 11 in Chrome and on an Android emulator.

On this MacBook, I am able to run flutter create to get the default counter app. It runs successfully in Chrome and on an iPhone 15 emulator. My project runs successfully in Chrome on this MacBook, but I'm still not able to get it working in the iPhone 15 emulator.

Below are my laptop specs and screenshots of what I'm seeing. Is there a place in VS Code that I can go to look at what's hanging the launch up?

Laptop Specs:
MacBook Pro 14-inch, 2023
Chip Apple M2 Pro
Memory 16 GB
macOS Ventura 13.5.2

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was able to resolve this by completely removing the packages in my project and one by one test them. The culprit was cloud_firestore. Once that was removed, my project worked on the iPhone 15 emulator.